# Recovering GRIB2 original values with python

Tags: python, grib-2

I have some GRIB2 files that I can dump with (for example) python-eccodes, or visualize with PanoplyJ. Sample python code:

```
import eccodes

f = open('myfile.grib2', 'rb')
gid = codes_grib_new_from_file(f)
 
values = eccodes.codes_get_values(gid)
num_vals = len(values)
for i in range(num_vals):
    print("%d %s" % (i + 1, values[i]))
```

From what I understand, the values I see are "compressed", that is, they are not the original values, but should be calculated using the formula `v = R + p * 2^E / 10^D` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843605/grib-file-to-text-in-java). My questions are:

- Is that really so, or does the python library automatically recompute them and show me the original value?
- If I have to calculate them with the above formula, is it possible to do that with common command-line tools from GDAL?

Thanks